# Error in UseMethod("estfun") : no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "coeftest"

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to do a Chow test in RStudio. I want to test if the earnings over time are influnced by external crises. Unfortunatley the data cannot stand up to the assumption of homoscedasticity.

I tried the following:

```
lm <- lm(earnings~time, data= data)
lm_cor <-coeftest(lm, vcov = vcovHC(lm, type = "HC4") )
sctest(lm_cor,type = "Chow", point = 1000)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "coeftest"
```

and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: `no applicable method for ...` in an error message hints that you're trying to apply a function to some object the function doesn't know how to deal with. Like in this case. Try applying `scstest` to the model, not to the `coeftest` result: `scstest(lm, ...)`.